# Looping over a Table B rows based on Table A values

Tags: sql

I am trying to built a SQL query using Table B and want to build a json type column in my query, using another table (table A)

```
Table A:

Id    Country    City
1     England    London        
2     England    Manchester
3     Spain      Madrid
4     Spain      Barcelona
5     Spain      Sevilla
```

```
Table B:

Id    Country
1     England    
2     Spain
```

Desired Outcome:

```
Id    Country   City_column
1     England   {'London': 'City', 'Manchester': 'City'}
2     Spain     {'Madrid': 'City', 'Barcelona': 'City', 'Sevilla': 'City'}
```

Intuitively, I would like to loop other the cities given a country value, but I am not sure how to do that.

I assume my query should look like this, but I am having trouble with the creation of the City Column and don't know how to start.

```
SELECT table_b.id,
table_b.country,
CAST(...) as City_column
FROM table_b
INNER JOIN table_a
ON table_a.Country = table_b.Country
```

Comment: Please mention your dbms with version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you are using a newer DB version, you can use the built-in JSON functions.
I would recommend using `JSON_ARRAYAGG`:

```sql
WITH 
  COUNTRIES (COUNTRY_ID, COUNTRY_NAME) AS
  (
    SELECT 1, 'England' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Spain' FROM DUAL
  ),
  CITIES (CITY_ID, COUNTRY_ID, CITY_NAME) AS
  (
    SELECT 1, 1, 'London' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 1, 'Manchester' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 2, 'Madrid' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 2, 'Barcelona' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 2, 'Sevilla' FROM DUAL
  )
SELECT c.country_name, 
       JSON_OBJECT('cities' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(ci.city_name ORDER BY ci.city_id)) AS ARRAY_EXAMPLE
FROM countries c
INNER JOIN cities ci ON c.country_id = ci.country_id
GROUP BY c.country_name;
```

This will produce the following result:

| COUNTRY_NAME | ARRAY_EXAMPLE |
| --- | --- |
| England | {"cities":["London","Manchester"]} |
| Spain | {"cities":["Madrid","Barcelona","Sevilla"]} |

I know I changed your data model a bit, but it hurt my heart seeing the country name in both tables.

Answer (score 1):

To complete Del's answer, which is probably the "proper" way of doing JSON, here is a classic (though a bit "hacky") SQL version which produces the output you want:

```
SELECT t1.country_id as Id, t1.country_name as Country, 
  concat( '\'{', group_concat(t2.city_name order by t2.city_id separator '\': \'City\', \''), '\': \'City\'}') as City_column
FROM countries t1
INNER JOIN cities t2 ON t1.country_id = t2.country_id
GROUP BY country_name;
```

Here is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c3b46/9